# How do I read the data a GPS chip gives me?

Tags: gps, microcontroller, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, nmea

I am working on a system involving a Raspberry Pi Pico reading the location of a GPS chip. I had some issues getting them communicating, but I have sorted them.

Now I have the data, I don't know how to interpret it into something that is useful for my application (Latitude and Longitude, and speed if it has it.) I have tried to do some research, but haven't really found anything definitive.

I am using a sr1612z1 GPS module with the provided antenna: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004218023349.html

Here is the data I am receiving:

```
$GNGLL,,,,,235950.000,V,M*6F
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,25.5,25.5,25.5,1*01
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,25.5,25.5,25.5,4*04
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,25.5,25.5,25.5,2*02
$GPGSV,3,1,10,05,25,120,27,10,17,279,21,13,34,130,24,15,66,111,20,0*6C
$GPGSV,3,2,1...
```

I used the micropython .split command on the list to split it at ',':

```py
buff = str(gpsModule.read())
parts = buff.split(',')
print(parts)
```

The resulting array is:

```
["b'$GNGLL", '', '', '', '', '235950.000', 'V', 'M*6F\\r\\n$GNGSA', 'A', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '25.5', '25.5', '25.5', '1*01\\r\\n$GNGSA', 'A', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '25.5', '25.5', '25.5', '4*04\\r\\n$GNGSA', 'A', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '25.5', '25.5', '25.5', '2*02\\r\\n$GPGSV', '3', '1', '10', '05', '25', '120', '27', '10', '17', '279', '21', '13', '34', '130', '24', '15', '66', '111', '20', '0*6C\\r\\n$GPGSV', '3', '2', "1'"]
```

I have tried googling how to interpret it and I think it is NMEA, but it seems to have too many sections in the list for it to fit any of the examples I found. I have a feeling however that the first $GPGSV is what I am after.

Comment: Read [NMEA Reference Manual](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/NMEA%20Reference%20Manual-Rev2.1-Dec07.pdf).

Comment: I formatted your question to make it better readable. But the received data look wrong. Please [edit] your question and add what this array represents, potentially correct the data. It seems as if there are multiple strings, separated by CR&LF. You are the only one who knows what you received, therefore I did not interpret the data.

Comment: use a dumb terminal program (minicom, etc) to see this information scroll by.  despite what documentation implies it can take fives to tens of minutes to lock on to a signal if it ever does.  indoors most for example will not.  Also not here it implies you need an antenna for this module (there are some of these cheap modules with an sma connector that if you connect an antenna will melt down something on the board)

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for editing, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks, I didn't see that before.

Comment: @old_timer After looking at the referance manual it seems that the data is incomplete. There was a status light on the module that said it was connected but I don't entirely trust it. I will try and find a really open spot and leave it there for 20min or so and see if that works.